# Is there a way to ad a onEditingChanged in a secure text field In swiftUi?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I was making a login page for an app I am working on and was adding offset to a textfield to it would move up when they keyboard popped up but when I tried it on the secure field I was not able to select onEditingChanged like I did on the regular textfield. I used this code for the Regular Textfeild:

```
TextField("Username", text: $username, onEditingChanged: { edit in  if edit == true {self.EditingMode = true} else {self.EditingMode = false }})
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 20)
```

And for the Secure Field I tried to use the same thing but it wouldn't work

```
SecureField("Password", text: $password)
  .padding()
  .background(lightGreyColor)
  .cornerRadius(5.0)
  .padding(.bottom, 20)
```

Comment: No, and taking into account that it is absent in SwiftUI 2.0 as well - it is intentional by design.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question because you have bizarre expressions like 'like I dod' and 'I sued this code.'  Segular Textfield?  What is it?

Comment: my bad I was typing to fast but I was asking that if there is a way to use the onEditing changed feature for a secure field like it is used in a regular textfield to set an offset when the keyboard pops up @ElTomato

Answer (score 4):

You could use the onTapGesture modifier

```
.onTapGesture {
    print("Password Field clicked")
}
```

Comment: I tried that but when I did I would get an error code : Contextual closure type '() -> Void' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Comment: This wouldn't grant you access to the onEditing changed closure that provides a bool value.

Answer (score 4):

```
@State private var isEditing: Bool = false

var body: some View {

   SecureField("Password", text: $password, onCommit: { isEditing = false })
        .onTapGesture {
            isEditing = true
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: where false condition or event lost focus of this?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. My understanding is that you’re asking when does isEditing return false so that the field will lose focus? isEditing is set to false when onCommit is called by the TextField.

Comment: the onTapGesture event works different from onEditingChanged. This one fires even if the field hasn't gained focus, but clicked on bounds.

Comment: on iOS 13 it works like a charm, except when clicking on different text field `onCommit` doesn't fire, and is editing doesn't become false. On iOS 15 and higher I advise y'all to use FocusState

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 15 there's a way to do this properly with [@FocusState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/FocusState)

e.g. changing an outline when focussed

```swift
struct TestLoginView: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case username
        case password
    }

    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
                .textFieldStyle(AuthTextFieldStyle(focused: focusedField == .username))

            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
                .textFieldStyle(AuthTextFieldStyle(focused: focusedField == .password))
        }
    }
}

struct AuthTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    var focused: Bool

    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding()
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4, style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(focused ? Color.blue : Color.black,
                            lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .padding(.vertical, 4)

    }
}
```

[image: SecureTextField focused example]

*****NOTE***** as of Xcode 14.2 the focus state update doesn't work in Previews, but does work on the Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example using the popular [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library.
I have used the isSelected property with CustomTextFieldStyle which is not included as implementation, but you can use the property as you wish.

```
struct CustomSecureTextField: View {
    
    class TFDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate, ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var isSelected = false
        
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            withAnimation {
                isSelected = true
            }
        }
        
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            withAnimation {
                isSelected = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    @StateObject var delegate = TFDelegate()
    
    var title: String = ""
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var onCommit: ()->()
    
    var body: some View {
        SecureField(title, text: $text, onCommit: onCommit)
            .textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle(isSelected: delegate.isSelected))
            .introspectTextField { textField in
                textField.delegate = self.delegate
            }
    }
    
    init(_ title: String = "", text: Binding<String>, onCommit: (()->())? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self._text = text
        self.onCommit = onCommit ?? {}
    }
    
    init(_ title: String = "", text: Binding<String?>, onCommit: (()->())? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self._text = Binding(get: {
            text.wrappedValue ?? ""
        }, set: {
            text.wrappedValue = $0.isEmpty ? nil : $0
        })
        self.onCommit = onCommit ?? {}
    }
    
    func editingCallback(isEditing: Bool) {
        withAnimation {
            delegate.isSelected = isEditing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to handle secure field focus is using a tap gesture that is recognized simultaneously with the normal `SecureField` gestures. This way a user can tap once to start focus and you still get a callback from the tap gesture.

```swift
@State private var isFocused: Bool = false
```

```swift
SecureField("", text: $text, onCommit: onCommit)
    .simultaneousGesture(
        TapGesture()
            .onEnded {
                isFocused = true
            }
    )
    .onSubmit {
        isFocused = false
    }
```